# Not sure how to create an object with Java Scanner and storing it inside an ArrayList

Tags: java, object, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I'm currently trying to make an Object with Java Scanner input.

This object `CashCard` contains the fields `amount`, `name` & `amountcardisused`.

But i'm not sure how i can get inputs from java `Scanner` and than move it inside my ArrayList CashCard.

This is mycode so far, i'm not sure how to continue, hopefully you can help me out.

Class `Cashcard`

```
package cashcard;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CashCard {

    private double amount;
    private String name;
    private int amountcardisused;
    private ArrayList<CashCard> listofcashcards;

    public CashCard(String name, double amount, int amountcardisused){
        this.amount = amount;
        this.name = name;
        this.amountcardisused = amountcardisused;
        listofcashcards = new ArrayList<CashCard>();
}

    public String setName(String name){
        return name;
    }
    public double setAmount(double amount){
        return amount;
    }
    public int setTimesCardIsUsed(int amountcardisused){
        return amountcardisused;
    }
}
```

Class `TestCashCard`

```
package cashcard;

import java.util.*;

public class TestCashCard {

    ArrayList<CashCard> listofcashcards = new ArrayList<CashCard>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input;

        // Stop console when entering 0 in console
        System.out.println("0: Stop Program");
        System.out.println("1: Add CashCard");

        // Execute this code when entering 1 in console
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter 0 or 1: ");
        input = in.nextLine();

        if(input.equals("0")){
        System.exit(0);
        }

        else if(input.equals("1")){

        System.out.print("Enter name of the card owner: ");
        String yourname = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the amount you want to set on your cashcard: ");
        double youramount = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter The Amount This Card Is Already Used: ");
        int youramountcardisused = in.nextInt();

        // Do Something to create an CashCard object by using the scanner its input 
        // and than put the object inside the ArrayList CashCard.
        // Need help on this part

    }

    else{
        System.out.print("No choice is made, close program");
        System.exit(0);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you have all three values that you need to call `CashCard` constructor. just call contructor to create object and then add it in list.

Comment: @Caleryn - He has list of `CashCard` in `TestCashCard` class as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CashCard` shouldn't contain an `ArrayList` of `CashCard` objects. You can remove that and keep your `ArrayList` in your main class.

So you could do this in your main:

```
ArrayList<CashCard> myCashCards = new ArrayList<CashCard>();

//Scanner input here.

CashCard cashCard = new CashCard(yourname, youramount, youramountcardisused);

myCashCards.add(cashCard);
```

Answer (score 0):

Only thing you have to do is

```
public CashCard(String name, double amount, int amountcardisused){
    this.amount = amount;
    this.name = name;
    this.amountcardisused = amountcardisused;
    //remove the below line from here
    listofcashcards = new ArrayList<CashCard>();// dont include this here
  }
```

and in your testcashcard class

after

```
  System.out.print("Enter The Amount This Card Is Already Used: ");
        int youramountcardisused = in.nextInt();
```

add

```
CashCard cashcard1 = new CashCard("abc",1000,2);

listofcashcards.add(cashcard1);
```

Comment: class name is `CashCard`

Answer (score 0):

If your desire is to keep a list of all created CashCards inside your CashCard class (rather than your test class), make your ArrayList field static, like so:

```
private double amount;
private String name;
private int amountcardisused;
// change your line below to this
private static ArrayList<CashCard> listofcashcards = new ArrayList<CashCard>();
```

Write two access methods for your ArrayList field (again in your CashCard class):

```
public static void addCashCard(CashCard cc) {
    listofcashcards.add(cc);
}

public static ArrayList<CashCard> getAllCashCards() {
    // Return new list copied from field (for field protection)
    return new ArrayList<CashCard>(listofcashcards);
}
```

Then, when you want to add a new card using your test class, use your constructor and the addCashCard method to store the new card in your shared field:

```
...

System.out.print("Enter The Amount This Card Is Already Used: ");
int youramountcardisused = in.nextInt();

// Create your object using the constructor, and add it to your list,
// which lives inside your CashCard class
CashCard.addCashCard(new CashCard(yourname, youramount, youramountcardisused));

...
```

Voila! If you want to access all your cards from your test class simply call CashCard.getAllCashCards()